# script triggering long running action in an interval crashes the app

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Why does this code crash the app and force me to close it?

```
public class ThreadE extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Do Time Consuming task!");
        setContentView(button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);}
        public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate thread.

Something like so

```
public class ThreadEActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, Runnable {

 private boolean running = false;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Button button = new Button(this);
   button.setText("Do Time Consuming task!");
   setContentView(button);
   button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 if (!running) { // prevent many threads when click repeats
   new Thread(this).start();  // Start the run method
 }
} 

@Override
public void run() {
 this.running = true;
 try {
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
     System.out.println(i);
     Thread.sleep(10000);
   }
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
 running = false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This class is extending Activity -- which means it will be on the Main/UI thread. You are calling Thread.sleep(10000) which is blocking the main thread for 10 seconds. This is bad practice for Android as you should never block the main thread. Try inheriting from Thread or AsyncTask for better results

Answer (score 0):

The system might kill a non-responding activity. I don't really see the point of this "test". Time consuming things should not run in the main thread either.